# Avoid having to copy referenced assemblies into application directory

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

When deploying new builds of applications, I find that applications built by another dev would have the structure:

- ApplicationName.exe
- ProprietaryClassLibrary.dll
- associated config files.

However, when I deploy a version I have built, I start to get "Could not load file or assembly" type errors.
These can be "resolved" by including the named assembly in the application folder. So now I would have (for example):

- ApplicationName.exe
- ProprietaryClassLibrary.dll
- System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll (for example)

But my question is- if these aren't references I've added, and the version hasn't changed, why do I now need to include them in the application folder?
I don't necessarily want to have to include copies of libraries that are already in the GAC or installed elsewhere on the server if I don't need to- but am open to suggestions on best practice.

I have checked my the references' settings in VS to change "Copy Local", "Specific Version" as well as Path, but with limited success.

Any pointers on what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I prefer to have everything that is used by my projects in my folder and not elsewhere waiting to be replaced or tampered by someone else installing its own app.

Comment: It depends on how you added the reference.  If it's by NuGet, then the assembly will get copied into your deployment folder.  If it's _Add Reference_ on a _.NET Framework_ app from the _Assemblies_ tab, then it references the GAC. If it's the _Projects_ tab, then it gets copied.  If you use the _Browse_ tab, then you really need to make sure that it gets copied (I avoid _Browse_).  In the .NET Core world, the GAC is either gone or nearly never used.  If you want to figure out what's failing, the _Fusion Log Viewer_ (fuslogvw.exe) can usually point you in the right direction

Comment: Really helpful, thanks Flydog. I think I've found that my dev machine has older versions in the GAC, which would contribute to this, as well as me faffing about with references